# Return generic class which extends Enum and implements and Interface-Java

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have an interface:

```
public MyInterface {};
```

And few enums which implement `MyInterface` as:

```
public enum MyFirstEnums implements MyInterface{};
```

In some another class, I need a method to return `Class` object such that
the Class should be like `MyFirstEnums`, which extends enum and implements MyInterface.

The return type of method should be: `<E extends Enum<?> & MyInterface>`, which should allow returning MyFirstEnums.class and like enums

I tried doing it like:

```
public <E extends Enum<?> & MyInterface> Class<E> getClazz(){
    return MyFirstEnums.class;
}
```

but this give me error as:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<MyFirstEnums> to Class<E>
```

What am I missing here?

At other place, I tried a method which takes such type of class as an argument and that worked fine:

```
public <E extends Enum<?> MyInterface> void doSomething(Class<E> myClazz){};
 //it rightly checks the type of myClazz while calling this method
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't just return the class object of `MyFirstEnum`. Your method is declared to return a class object that corresponds to an enum and implements `MyInterface` but it could be an enum other than `MyFirstEnum` that also meets this criteria. Imagine you have another enum:

```
public enum MySecondEnum implements MyInterface { }
```

You could also do:

```
Class<MySecondEnum> clazz = getClazz();
```

The compiler infers the type argument from the target return type of `clazz` (`E` is inferred as `MySecondEnum`). In this case, clearly a runtime exception is likely to occur. For example, when you try to instantiate an object from the returned class, you would get a `java.lang.InstantiationException`.

Note that your method does not actually use the type argument, so why have it generic in the first place?

If you want a "generic" way to return class objects for each enum implementing the interface, you can do something like:

```
abstract class EnumProvider<E extends Enum<?> & MyInterface> {
    ...
    public abstract Class<E> getClazz();
}


class MyFirstEnumProvider extends EnumProvider<MyFirstEnums> {
    ...
    @Override
    public Class<MyFirstEnums> getClazz() {
        return MyFirstEnums.class;
    }

}
```

Comment: I do have other such enums which implement MyInterface and that's what my objective is: to allow all such type of enums to be returned. How can I do that? Method is not using type argument but it is using that as return type. Does that not make sense?

Comment: @Anmol It clearly does not make sense to the compiler. If you just want to return `MyFirstEnums.class`, the return type should just be `Class<MyFirstEnums>`. I have updated the answer with a possible generic solution.

Comment: Thanks! This works as per the OP. Didn't mention it in the OP but I was trying to define this kind of method in an another enum class, wherein each enum instance shall return different Class which extends Enum and implemented MyInterface. I think I made something complex, working on a simpler way to serve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would try some response:

You want to define a method which return some class type which is not fully defined, but which respects: extends Enum & MyInterface.

And your Class is not passed to the method.

I have a doubt it is not possible or safe.

I would :

1 pass a Class I want as an argument

2 inverse the test: I test inside if Class< E> extends   Enum & MyInterface and  MyFirstEnum.class and if MyFirstEnum.class extends class< E>

3 of course Class result=MyFirstEnum.class; can be more sophisticated and not known before...

This compiles (because tests are made at runtime) but I dont know if it can help you.

```
public  <E> Class<E> getClazz(Class< E> _return_class) throws Exception
    {
    Class result=MyFirstEnum.class;

    if (MyInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(_return_class) )
        if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(_return_class))
            if (_return_class.isAssignableFrom(result))

        return (Class<E>) result;

 throw new Exception("Bad Class");
}
```